# How to get month start and end date from month number using pyspark and python

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

There is one column having month number, need to create tow columns month start date and month end date.

If month = 3 we want month start date as 3/1/2022 and month end date as 3/31/2022

How to do it in pyspark and python

Comment: You need in python or pyspark?

Comment: any of these will be fine. Would prefer pyspark code

Comment: How do  you determine year?

Answer (score 0):

If the year is always fixed then you can do

```
df = df.withColumn('start_date', F.expr("to_date(2022 || '-' || month)"))
df = df.withColumn('last_date' , F.expr('last_day(start_date)'))
```

Sample Result

```
df.show()

+-----+----------+----------+
|month|start_date| last_date|
+-----+----------+----------+
|    1|2022-01-01|2022-01-31|
|    2|2022-02-01|2022-02-28|
|    5|2022-05-01|2022-05-31|
|   08|2022-08-01|2022-08-31|
+-----+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle the given date format, we need [unix_timestamp()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp.html) date function of pyspark like this, also assuming the year = 2022

```
from pyspark.sql.context import SparkContext as sc
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Row
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("handling_datetime").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

# Recreating the month column in a dataframe
month = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(month)
rowrdd = rdd1.map(lambda x: Row(x))
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rowrdd,['month'])

df1.show()

# +-----+
# |month|
# +-----+
# |    1|
# |    2|
# |    3|
# |    4|
# |    5|
# |    6|
# +-----+

# Building the new columns 
df2 = df1.withColumn('month_startdate', f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(f.concat_ws("/",f.col('month'),f.lit('1'),f.lit('2022')),"MM/dd/yyyy"), "MM/dd/yyyy").cast("string"))\
.withColumn('month_enddate', f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(f.last_day(f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(f.col('month_startdate'),'MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')),'MM/dd/yyyy'),'MM/dd/yyyy'))

df2.show()

# +-----+---------------+-------------+
# |month|month_startdate|month_enddate|
# +-----+---------------+-------------+
# |    1|     01/01/2022|   01/31/2022|
# |    2|     02/01/2022|   02/28/2022|
# |    3|     03/01/2022|   03/31/2022|
# |    4|     04/01/2022|   04/30/2022|
# |    5|     05/01/2022|   05/31/2022|
# |    6|     06/01/2022|   06/30/2022|
# +-----+---------------+-------------+
```